# Creating and updating a status panel

Tags: .net, powershell, paint, statusbar

I'm trying to make a GUI in powershell using some .net and given my small amount of experience writing GUI based programs I'm running into trouble updating a label.

I'm just making a simple form that has a label, and I want the label to be replaced each time a folder name is read.  The idea is to mimic a status window for a program that takes some time to run and updates a panel with information on the progress of the program.

Here is my code:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Height = 350
$form.Width = 600

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = "first label"
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.showDialog()

$dir = ls C:\ -Directory
[int]$i = 0

while($i -lt $dir.Count) {

   $label.Text = $dir[$i].Name
   $form.Controls.Add($label)
   $form.paint
   sleep 3 # Added this just to make sure I'm not missing the display
   $i++
}
```

I assume there needs to be a call to paint, but I'm not sure how that would update the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to your question. I replace `$form.ShowDialog()` by `$form.Show()`. I also add the `$form.Close()` at the end but the result is not so good for me ; look at the end for a more PowerShell solution.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Height = 350
$form.Width = 600

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = "first label"
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Show()

$dir = ls C:\ -Directory
[int]$i = 0

while($i -lt $dir.Count) {

   $label.Text = $dir[$i].Name
   $form.Controls.Add($label)
   #$form.paint
   sleep 1 # Added this just to make sure I'm not missing the display
   $i++
}

$form.Close()
```

**Coding advice** : Consider using *foreach* loop in spite of a *while* loop here `foreach ($file in $dir)`. No need here to type `$i` as an `int`. In scripts try to use CmdLet full name (Get-ChilItem), and not aliases (ls, dir ...), even if they are common aliases, it's more readable. Don't get upset, you can forget this ;o)

**Now my advice** on the way you decide to handle your problem. PowerShell provides some stuff to show progress. Here is a small example :

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem C:\ -Directory
$i = 0
foreach($dir in $dirs)
{
   Write-Progress -Activity "looking for Directories" -status "Found $($dir.fullname)" -percentComplete ($i*100 / $dirs.count)
   sleep 1 # Added this just to make sure I'm not missing the display
   $i++
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to write the progress area inside of the GUI?

Comment: Yes if you run my sample with PowerShell ISE you will have it as grapgic

Comment: Another solution is to use WindowsForm or WPF and use the correct graphic Object. This way you shouls use a job and a way to comunicate, or write your own .net object.

Comment: Yes JP, that works, but it's separate from my form.  I'm trying to added it into my form so that it works as one single unit (if that makes sense).

Comment: Yup, I used start-job the way you described!  Also, thanks a lot for the other suggestions that you provided.  They are all very helpful.